# Materializecss + Angular Cli - Select component not dropping down correctly

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize

I am using [materializecss](https://materializecss.com) in my `angular-cli` project and in my project, all the select components are with the behaviour of image bellow:

[image: Problem happening]

When clicking first time, no component works correctly, they not drop down at the first click, only with the second click that shows up the content.

Follow bellow the select code:

```
<select [ngModel]="initialValue" class="maintextcolor" (ngModelChange)="changeCategory($event)" id="selectCategory"
            materialize="material_select">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione</option>
   <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option._id">{{option.name}}</option>
</select>
```

I saw at github some suggestions like:

First try:

```
$('#selectCategory').material_select();
document.querySelectorAll('.select-wrapper').forEach(t => t.addEventListener('click', e=>e.stopPropagation()))
```

second try

```
$('select').material_select();
$('select').change((e) => {
   this.model[e.currentTarget.name] = e.currentTarget.value;
 });
```

but It does not work properly.
Are there any suggestions how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: my suggestion would be using angular material. angular material components are ultimate if you want to use material design in your app.

Comment: @sibabratswain Thanks for your comment. Really I am considering to change to Angular Material, but before I need to test if I will have many layout issues to fix after migration.

Comment: You have to call the function basically after getting all the options. You could use `setTimeOut` while calling `material_select ()`. check out my solution in stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used **materializecss** for the first time to solve/check your issues. And it works perfectly fine.

Please have a look at this. First I have added cdns to my index.html file

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Then I have added the html like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <select>
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
                <option value="{{option.value}}"  *ngFor="let option of options">{{option.name}}</option>
            </select>
            <label>Materialize Select</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in my ts file added these two javascript lines

```
ngOnInit() {
   setTimeout(()=>{
      const elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
      const instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, 'options');
    });
 }
```

I see it works fine. 
[image]

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxamc2)